# URL PHP basic authentication is this a security issue?

Tags: php, authentication, url

Let's say, I do have an URL like this:

> http://mywebsite.com:8080/get.php?username=JohnDoe&password=FfolBdKf2K

And also I'm sharing this URL with only John Doe, so if he calls this URL he will get on that specific content.

**My question is now about the security site of a link like this:**

Lets imagine that one `HACKER` know's that he can access with a URL like mentioned above to specific content.
What he has to know is only about existing `username` and `password`.

- So how hard is that for this `HACKER` to find out `username` and
  `password` in this case?
- Are there any tools, which can scan the website (`http://mywebsite.com:8080/get.php?`) for valid `username` and `password` ?

**Please note, I know:**

- That anyone which calls this URL can access to this specific content. But this is not that point on this question. Im interested in more the security site of this kind of a URL.
- This URL is not HTTPS, so the man-in-the-middle attack would also be possible. But this would be valid for only the accessed URL, not for other  created URL's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad. You should at least have SSL encrypted traffic because with your current approach it's sufficient to sniff the http traffic to get your credentials. There are tools for that - no knowledge required.

No there are no easy way to guess if given url expects login and pass arguments, but you can always try in blind and see what would happen. Then, once it's known that such type of args would work, it's just matter of getting the right credentials - there are tools to easily run brute force attack on that url.

Comment: I know. Posted too quick. Edited

Comment: What do they at least know to start with a brute fore attack - the login name?

Comment: Brute force means they know nothing so may flood you with tons of requests trying popular words for both login and pass (there are ready dictionaries available for that). Sure, having login `hdhxukeksikjwjs+sgehsh` and pass `7#+$+2)/;$$3i` is better than `john`/`sessame`, but statistics say the latter is more likely to be the case.